# undefined symbol: rb_thread_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hi I have working with rbenv and using rails application it is working good, when I switched application to another computer , After bundle install

When I run "rails s" or "bundle exec rails s"

This is error come

*/home/{user}/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: /home/{user}/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/pg-0.13.2/pg_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_thread_select*

can anyone guide how to overcome this solution

Answer (score 11):

The pg gem you are using `0.13.2` is referencing to a ruby method `rb_thread_select`, which is not present in `2.2.0`+. It was there in the older version of ruby. So you can't use that version of pg in ruby `2.2.0`+.

Upgrade to a version `0.15.0` +, which doesn't use `rb_thread_select`

Comment: @AliAbbas do accepts and upvote this answer, if it helped you. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes I go to previous ruby version